# Using Browserify to Import Smooth Scroll

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I'm not sure if I'm understanding Browserify correctly, but am I able to essentially `require()` this [smooth-scroll](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll) plugin (installed via npm) in my `app.js` file and Browserify will bundle it all together in my final `app.js` file?

**app.js**

```
var ss = require('./smooth-scroll');

$(document).ready(function(){
  ss.init();
});
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
  var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
    var b = browserify(filename);
    return b.bundle();
  });

  return gulp.src('./src/js/app.js')
    .pipe(browserified)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/js'))
});
```

**Update**

So, I'm trying to create my own module using the answer below but I'm having a problem in getting it to work with [jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js).

**adaptive-backgrounds.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery');

module.exports = function(){

  /* jshint debug: true, expr: true */
  ;(function($){

    /* Constants & defaults. */
    var DATA_COLOR    = 'data-ab-color';
    var DATA_PARENT   = 'data-ab-parent';
    var DATA_CSS_BG   = 'data-ab-css-background';
    var EVENT_CF      = 'ab-color-found';

    ...

};
```

**app.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery');
var ab = require('./vendors/adaptive-backgrounds');

$(function(){
  $.ab.run();
});
```

For some reason the adaptive backgrounds plugin doesn't seem to be running on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, if **Smooth Scroll** is available as a **npm** module. If it´s not you can create your own module with the script. Then, **browserify** would bundle everything into one js file.

Or you could just add it to your web page before your bundle, as you would normally do, and then it would be accessible from the bundle since it would be declared in global scope. But in this case, keep in mind you should concatenate your scripts for production (in the right order) to reduce the page loading time by minimizing the number of http requests.

Creating your own module is really simple. Let's say **Smooth Scroll** wasn't available as **npm** module, you could simply wrap the plugin in an anonymous function and assign that function to `module.exports` and then call the related variable in your bundle when you `require` the modified plugin.

Your plugin would then look like this:

```
/*!
 * jQuery Smooth Scroll - v1.5.2 - 2014-10-01
 * https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Karl Swedberg
 * Licensed MIT (https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll/blob/master/LICENSE-MIT)
 */

//WE ADD THIS, BECAUSE ITS A DEPENDENCY (downloaded with npm)
var jQuery = require('jquery');

//AND THIS
module.exports = function(){

    //THIS IS THE ORIGINAL CODE
    (function($) {
        var version = '1.5.2',
        optionOverrides = {},
        defaults = {
          exclude: [],
          excludeWithin:[],
          offset: 0,
        //....

//AND WE CLOSE OUR FUNCTION
};
```

And in the bundle you would do something like this

```
var SmoothScroll = require('../jquery.smooth-scroll');
var $ = require('jquery');

SmoothScroll();
// From now on Smooth Scroll is available

$('#mydiv').smoothScroll();
```

Something to note: you could have simply assigned the existing immediate anonymous function wrapping the plugin code to `module.exports` and then simply calling `require('./jquery.smooth-scroll')` would have make it available in the current scope. But imo it's better practice to wrap it with another anonymous function to do a call to make the plugin available to current scope explicitly.

**Update**

For your plugin, you should first do
`npm install jquery`. Because jquery as a regular script isn't exported as a module. So you need to install jquery module (or you could do the export yourself but why reinventing the wheel?)

Then...

**adaptive-backgrounds.js**

```
//Here you have to call your variable jQuery since its named this way when
//it's passed as an argument to the plugin immediate function
var jQuery = require('jquery');

module.exports = function(){

  /* jshint debug: true, expr: true */
  (function($){

    /* Constants & defaults. */
    var DATA_COLOR    = 'data-ab-color';
    var DATA_PARENT   = 'data-ab-parent';
    var DATA_CSS_BG   = 'data-ab-css-background';
    var EVENT_CF      = 'ab-color-found';

    ...

  // This is what I meant
  })(jQuery);
};
```

**app.js**

```
//Now you can use $
var $ = require('jquery');
var ab = require('./vendors/adaptive-backgrounds');

//add this to call the immediate function used to set up the plugin
ab();

$(function(){
  $.ab.run();
});
```

Comment: I'm thinking of that edge-case. Is it easy to create your own module with a script that isn't available over npm?

Comment: I've updated my question based on your answer. Having problems in getting the plugin to run... Any ideas?

Comment: The jquery your importing isn't a node module. you should install it with `npm install jquery`.  You forgot a semi-colon too in front of the parenthesis wrapping the immediate inner function (after  /* jshint debug: true, expr: true */). And one last thing, you have to call `ab()` in your app.js for the plugin to be available because you're wrapping it in a function and not assigning directly the immediate function to module.exports.

Comment: I updated my answer, you had another error too. In adaptative-background.js you named jquery as $ but it should be named jQuery in that instance because the library expect jQuery variable to be in global scope.

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work with the updated answer. I've got jQuery installed via npm and I'm requiring it like this: `require('jquery/dist/jquery')` in both **adaptive-backgrounds.js** and **app.js** files.

Comment: I wonder, do I have to add something to my **gulpfile.js** that allows **adaptive-backgrounds.js** to require jQuery from the `/node_modules` folder...?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I'm requiring jQuery like so in both files:  `require('jquery');`.

Comment: Ok. Silly me! Turns out `$.adaptiveBackground.run();` is the correct way to run the script and NOT `$.ab.run();`. Problem solved! Thanks so much for all your help @FelixD.